# Process Inbound 997

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-deployment

Process Inbound 997

I have following scenario:

I have multiple parties configure in BizTalk. And I am sending many EDIs at the same time to many parties i.e.

1. 850 EDI sent to Party A
2. 850 EDI sent to Party B
3. 850 EDI sent to Party B
4. 850 EDI sent to Party A

After sending above four EDI, I’ll have four inbound 997 in my inbox.

What is the best way to process all found inbound 997? And how do I come correlate any perticular 997 to Specific EDI?

Answer (score 0):

The 997 should have reference the group control number of the outbound document.

So if you send a PO to A, that document will have a group control number (GS06), which should be unique to that document.

In other words, the group control number should increment for each "group" sent to your trading partner.

When the 997 comes in (assuming BizTalk doesn't reconcile this for you), you can look at the AK102 to determine what outbound group it refers to.

Most EDI translator / communication platforms do this automatically for you.  Unless I'm missing something in your question, and it doesn't, then you'll probably want to create a process that a) captures the outbound group control number and b) reconciles it on the way back in.

Please note it's been many, MANY years since I looked at BizTalk, but EDI is EDI.